# What's the correct interpretation of a pushforward measure?

Tags: probability

I will take an example. Our sample space if $\Omega = [0,1] \times \cdots = [0,1]^\infty$. Given a point $\omega \in \Omega$, let $\pi_n$ be $n$-th projection. By theorem in probability, $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure such that

1. $\forall n \in \mathbb N$: $\pi_n$ is a random variable with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.
2. The sequence $\{\pi_n\}_n$ is independent.

Consider a random walk of probability 1/2. Define random variable \begin{equation*} \nu_n = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if $\pi_n \geq 1/2$} \\ -1 &\text{if $\pi_n < 1/2$} \end{cases}\end{equation*}

**Question:** To evaluate probability such that $\pi_n = 1$, is this the correct procedure?
\begin{align*}
\pi_{n*}\nu_{n*}\mathbb P(\{1\}) = \nu_{n*}\mathbb P (\pi_n^{-1}(\{1\})) = \nu_{n*}\mathbb P ([\frac{1}{2}, 1]) = \mathbb P (\nu_n^{-1}[\frac{1}{2}, 1]) = \mathbb P(\{\omega \mid \nu_n(\omega) \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]\}) = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

**Question 2:** How can I calculate probability that $X_n = l$, where $X_n := \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_n$? I mean, I know how to calculate its probability by more elementary means, but I do not know how to set up an equation in measure-theoretic context.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X_n = l) = \mathbb P(\pi_1 + \cdots + \pi_n = l) =_* \binom{n}{\frac{n+l}{2}}
\end{align*}
For the equality $(=_*)$ above, I took the following procedure:

1. First, note that $n+l$ must be even.
2. Then, $\frac{n+l}{2}$ of $\pi_i$'s are 1.
3. Hence, there are $\binom{n}{\frac{n+l}{2}}$ ways of choosing such $\pi_i$'s.

While I can calculate the probability, I am not sure how to express the steps above in measure-theoretic context. I am very new to probability, so a methodical step-by-step would be very much appreciated.